# Malformed line in the source.list debian posgres

Tags: debian, apt, source

I would like to start by saying that I am beginner and that probably I "broke" the source list

The story is:

1. while trying to do updates in debian, I was receiving error messages saying that it was impossible to access the URL of the source list
2. I have tried to modify the source list, and now when i try to do updates (i.e. `apt-get update`), I receive and error message saying that the line 4 is malformed

Here is my `sources.list`

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt
```

Also: the command `gedit` is not installed, and now that the source list is malformed, I am not able to install it

Suggestions?

Best,
Riccardo

Comment: Thank you for the extra detail. I've formatted the file like I asked you to do - selecting the text and using the `{}` button

Answer (score 3):

Neither line three nor line four is valid. You have omitted the leading `deb` and also the name of the respository it's supposed to be referencing.

To fix that without an editor it's going to be easiest just to delete them and start over.

Run these commands as root (`sudo -s`),

```
cd /etc/apt
grep '^deb' sources.list > tmp
mv sources.list sources.list.broken
mv tmp sources.list

apt update
```

If you get an error at any point, stop and recheck what you typed.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I am using your commands, but when I get to the apt update, it gives me the same error message malformed line. Does it make sense?

Comment: @RiccardoFerrazzo provided you did the other four lines successfully, you should have only two lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file - the first two lines starting with `deb`.

Comment: Then probably the issue is with the first commands - they do not return anything, and then I have a mistake when I get to apt update.

Comment: They won't print anything to your terminal, if that's what you're suggesting. After the `grep` runs you will have two lines in the file `tmp`.